Does there exist harmonic function $f$ of the form $f(x,y)=u(x^2 y)$?
We can easily find that
$\displaystyle\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}=4x^2y^2u''(x^2y)+2yu'(x^2y)$
$\displaystyle\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}=x^4u''(x)$
If we want function $f$ to be harmonic it has to satisfy the Laplacian equation on $\mathbb{R}^2$ of the following form: $\displaystyle\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial x^2}+\displaystyle\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y^2}=0$. Continuing from here we get a differential equation of the second order which I'm struggling to solve:
$$(x^4+4x^2y^2)u''(x^2y)+2yu'(x^2y)=0$$
I've tried with substitution $t=x^2y$, but this didn't get me anywhere since I couldn't get rid of either $x$ or $y$.
Is it possible that such harmonic function $f$ does not exist? If so, than how to prove it?

$u$ is a function of just one variable.  If you let $x^2 y = t$, so $y = t/x^2$, your differential equation says
$$ \left(x^4 + \frac{4 t^2}{x^2} \right) u''(t) + \frac{2t}{x^2} u'(t) = 0$$
so (if $u'' \ne 0$) $$ x^6 = -4 t^2 - 2 t \frac{u'(t)}{u''(t)} $$
which is impossible because the left side depends on $x$ and the right doesn't.   The only possibility that works is $u' = 0$ (i.e. $u$ constant).

Since $u$ is a function of only $1$ variable you can arbitrarily set $x=1$
to get the ODE $(1+4y^2)u''(y)+2yu'(y)=0$
This solves to $u'(t)=a\cdot(1+4t^2)^{-\frac 14}$
Reporting in $\Delta f(x,y)=\dfrac{2ay(1-x^6)}{(1+4x^4y^2)^\frac 54}=0$ for all $x,y$ implies $a=0$ meaning $u$ is constant function.
